# Лексическая ошибка

Tags: лексика

Добрый день! Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить лексическую ошибку.

> Наверное, для баловства ради он приложил руку к сегодняшнему имиджу этих певцов.

Спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем предожении лишним является слово "для". Надо: Наверное, баловства ради он приложил руку к сегодняшнему имиджу этих певцов. Другой вариант: Наверное, ради баловства он приложил руку к сегодняшнему имиджу этих певцов.

Comment: Спасибо. ) Понятно. ) Как сразу не заметила. ) Для - ради (плеоназм).
"Приложить руку к имиджу", наверное, уместно, т.е. принять участие в создании имиджа. Не  так ли? Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Принять участие в создании имиджа ради баловства? Не знаю... Посмотрим, что скажут остальные участники.

Answer (score 0):

Виктор, а разве можно приложить руку к имиджу? Т.е. баловства ради иметь отношение к имиджу? Мне кажется, здесь ошибкой является и сам фразеологизм. Что скажете?

Comment: Фраза звучит шутливо, а в шутке это вполне, мне кажется, допустимо. В серьезном тексте, несомненно, это звучало бы диковато